# Share Custom User model between two Django projects (same db)

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

i have two Django project, sharing the same DB (postgres)

The first one is an onboarding project for the users where i store the user data.
The second one is the project where all the entities related to the user are.

For example project one has only Users, project two has Cars and those two models are going to be related.

I want to get the users from the first project and "use" them in the second one.

I read some articles on how to do this, it seems that i should recreate the User model on `project 2` and fake the migrations but i don't really like this way.

I'm new to Django can you please help me understanding the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: are you using the same database name in Postgres? or have you 2 databases in a single Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the custom user model in all your projects and make one model managed, which project will handle user creation and updation parts and all others can be unmanaged models.

```py
# Project 1
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
    class Meta:
        managed = True
    ...
```

```py
# Project n
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
    class Meta:
        managed = False
    ...
```

Check [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#managed) out for more information